# How can we model intrinsic curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, curvature

Can it only be done in Euclidean space? Doesn't Euclidean space only model extrinsic curvature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Euclidian space is not necessary.  You can "model" intrinsic curvature using the beautiful language of Riemannian geometry, whose great triumph was formulating a vocabulary that lets you talk about the curvature of a space without making reference to an extrinsic space in which the curved space is embedded: hence the term intrinsic.

This is crucial to general relativity, since embedding a curved 4-space in flat Euclidean space requires that the Euclidean space be ten-dimensional, and dealing with that embedding would suck.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by the term "model" in this context, but:

If a space is a Euclidean space, in the sense that it has a Euclidean metric, then its Levi Civita connection (the connection compatible with its metric) has no intrinsic curvature (for example a flat plane is like this).  However, it may be given some extrinsic curvature by means of an embedding into a higher dimensional space (the flat plane may be rolled up into a cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

But if you were a two dimensional organism living on the cylinder, you couldn't detect this extrinsic curvature by locally measuring angles and distances.

Comment: Very clear. How can one relate both metrics?